# How to link JQuery/Javascript file to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having issues with my JQuery code functioning when I open my file (locally saved) in a web browser. When I apply the same code to JSFiddle, all of it works.

This is what I have in the *heading* of my HTML file:

```
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="main.css"/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

My css file is named "main.css" and my JQuery/Javascript file is named "script.js".

Do I have a syntax error or anything in the *heading*?

Comment: What's going wrong? You need to describe the behavior and/or provide an error message.

Comment: this is good, maybe you are put css and js to some folder? :P

Comment: Are your HTML, CSS, and JS files all in the same directory?

Comment: @MikeC There's no error message. The only issue is that none of my JQuery code has any effect. Yet it worked in JSFiddle, which has led me to believe that there is an issue with linking. My .js, .html, and .css files are all in the same directory, which confuses me.

Comment: @showdev Could there possibly be an error in the ordering of my "script" and "link", or does that even matter? All of my files are under the same directory.

Comment: As long as your jquery-ui.js is before your script.js it should be ok. I don't think it would matter but you could try adding the `type` attribute to your first `<script>` tag. Also, it looks like you're mixing single quotes and double quotes. Maybe that's making things act weird..

Comment: @Jmh2013 I changed everything to double quotes, and added "type="text/javascript"" to the first script tag. However, it still doesn't work. Is there any way I can more directly show you the effects of my code? Possibly showing you a picture of what's happening?

Comment: Have you checked your [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for 404s or javascript error messages?

Comment: @Jmh2013 I have taken screenshots of the code being run both on JSFiddle and locally (being opened in a web browser).

In JSFiddle: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/28u3ay0/8)
I can click on the image of the printer and the list of available printers shows up.

In a web browser: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2af0bj7/8)
After clicking on the image of the printer, nothing shows up.

Comment: @showdev The browser console gives me the following error messages:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 

I'm not clear as to where it can be going wrong. It's under the same directory and I believe the script and link tags are correct.

Comment: Have you included jQuery? jQueryUI requires it.

Comment: yup @showdev is probably right. Should have seen that from the beginning.

Comment: @showdev What do you mean by "include jQuery"? Is this in the HTML file itself or in the directory? 

I apologize, I'm new to jQuery, HTML, and CSS so I'm not familiar with setting them up.

Comment: No worries. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a javascript library, separate from [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/). jQueryUI requires jQuery in order to function. You might check out the [basic overview](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/#basic-overview-using-jquery-ui-on-a-web-page) for jQueryUI.

Comment: add this before your jquery-ui.js.. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` or you could download the Jquery.js file from [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: @JeffreyTai You are saying there is no 404 error for your JavaScript, yet the jQuery doesn't work? Did you wrap your jQuery with `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`?

Comment: @showdev When I open my file through Firefox, I still get this error: "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

What I have in my head tag: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2vnhtud/8)

What I have in my local directory: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/20pvdzs/8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should (almost) always surround your jQuery with `$(document).ready(function() { ... code here ... });`. The reason why this works is because it forces the entire document to load before executing the JavaScript inside. If the JavaScript executes before the document has fully loaded, it may throw errors (and other crazy stuff).

This is not necessary, however, if you place your JavaScript at the very bottom of your HTML document (above the `</body>` tag).

The shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {})` is `$(function() {})`.